# How should I write in order to save this variable in a csv file

Tags: python, selenium

with open('Test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

```
next(csv_reader)

for line in csv_reader:
    driver.get(line[0])

    Name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "banner-title").text
    
    with open('Test1.csv', mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
       for row in Name:
        csv_writer.writerow(Name)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question isn't clear, there isn't enough information to be able to give an answer. What is your input, what is your current output, and what is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: For every line returned from the *csv_reader* iterable you will create a new Test1.csv file. Try opening it in mode 'w' on the first iteration and 'a' thereafter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a way that I can ensure that which column is it appending to in a CSV file?